# What does mean "quality-free content"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have stepped on the following sentence:

> There is an unsigned agreement between publishers and advertisers of
>   providing quality-free content in returns of advertising.

What does mean "quality-free content" in this sentence?

Comment: It certainly needs stepping on! Where did you step on it? The Google search can't find it anywhere, so I suspect you found it in print. Without context, any answer can only be a guess.

Comment: This is the opening sentence of one-pager html from our content writer. The one-pager is devoted to adblock and internet advertisements.

Comment: **quality-free** with the hyphen means **without quality**, useless, worthless. It carries a _negative connotation._ Are you _sure_ your writer included the hyphen? If so, the writer is probably not an English speaker, unless the writer _intended_ to say _"There is an unsigned agreement between publishers and advertisers of providing worthless content in returns of advertising."_ But even _without_ the hyphen, honestly, the sentence does not make much sense in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the hyphen is misplaced, unless it's meant ironically. In the phrase

> quality free content

both *quality* and *free* would be adjectives modifying the noun *content*. That could be rephrased as *content of good quality which you don't have to pay for* (because of the advertisements).

As it stands, it reads more like *content without any quality* which is basically the opposite.

We'd need more context than just this single sentence to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the same.

What about "in returns of advertising"? Should not it be "in return for advertising"? Or maybe "in return for advertisement"? Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @rlib no problem, but you're asking another question right now. This is about "quality-free content", not about the rest of the sentence. You should ask a new question about that, but you should really add more detail to your questions. Otherwise, we're just guessing.